# OVM: how to get test name in a class which declared inside the env?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

We are using OVM not UVM:

I have tried using:

```
ovm_root::get().ovm_test_top.sprint();
```

But I get this error:

> Could not find member 'ovm_test_top' in class 'ovm_root', at
>   ".../ovm_root.svh", 
>     68.

There I see:

```
/* deprecated */ ovm_component ovm_test_top;
```

Any ideas what should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ovm_test_top` is the string name of the top level test. You can do

```
ovm_component test;
string testname;
test = ovm_root::get().find("ovm_test_top");   
testname = test.get_type_name();
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! I thought ovm_test_top is the instance name.. Trying to understand - why there is no instance name to this component?